# Objects added to a PriorityQueue are not ordered by their priority

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, compareto

I'm trying to implement a heap using a PriorityQueue as follows:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
Set<String> allWords = codebook.getAllWords();
for(String word : allWords)
{
    heap.add(new Node(word, codebook.getProbability(word)));
    System.out.println(heap.toString());
}
```

Where I've defined Node as as private class inside the same class that holds the above method. Node is defined as:

```
private static class Node implements Comparable
{
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;
    protected String name;
    protected double frequency;
    public Node(String n, double f)
    {
        name = n;
        frequency = f;
    }
    public Node(double f, Node l, Node r)
    {
        frequency = f;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) 
    {
        Node other = (Node)(arg0);
        if(this.frequency < other.frequency)
        {
            System.out.println(name + " < " + other.name);
            return -1;
        }
        else if(this.frequency > other.frequency)
        {
            System.out.println(name + " > " + other.name);
            return 1;
        }
        System.out.println(name + " is equal to " + other.name);
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {return name;}
}
```

However, when I add nodes to the PriorityQueue, they are not ordered by frequency. Based on output from my println statements, the correct values are returned by Node.compareTo(). For example, given the dataset:

- name, frequency
- need, 3
- cat, 1
- neat, 2

My code produces:
// add need
[need]
// add cat
cat < need
[cat, need]
// add neat
neat > cat
[cat, need, neat]
when the PriorityQueue should be [cat, neat, need]
Any tips as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order from an [iterator for `PriorityQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator%28%29) is undefined; the order when calling `poll()` should be the comparator ordering.  From the API spec,

> `iterator()` Returns an iterator over the elements
>   in this queue. The iterator does not
>   return the elements in any particular
>   order.

If what you really need is a sorted set, use `SortedSet` OR put things into a collection and use `Collections.sort()`.  If, however, you really need a pqueue, here's my example fix:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;


public class TestPriorityQueue 
{
  static Map<String,Double> codebook = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  static {
    codebook.put("need", 3.0);
    codebook.put("cat", 1.0);
    codebook.put("neat", 2.0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    test();
  }

  public static void test() {
    PriorityQueue<Node> heap = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
    Set<String> allWords = codebook.keySet();
    for (String word : allWords) {
      heap.add(new Node(word, codebook.get(word)));
      System.out.println(heap.toString());
    }

    System.out.println("In order now:");
    while(!heap.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(heap.poll());
    }
  }

  private static class Node implements Comparable<Node>
  {
      protected Node left;
      protected Node right;
      protected String name;
      protected double frequency;
      public Node(String n, double f)
      {
          name = n;
          frequency = f;
      }
      public Node(double f, Node l, Node r)
      {
          frequency = f;
          left = l;
          right = r;
      }

      @Override
      public int compareTo(Node arg0) 
      {
          if(this.frequency < arg0.frequency)
          {
              System.out.println(name + " < " + arg0.name);
              return -1;
          }
          else if(this.frequency > arg0.frequency)
          {
              System.out.println(name + " > " + arg0.name);
              return 1;
          }
          System.out.println(name + " is equal to " + arg0.name);
          return 0;
      }

      public String toString()
      {return name;}
  }

}
```

Gives:

```
[need]
cat < need
[cat, need]
neat > cat
[cat, need, neat]
In order now:
neat < need
cat
neat
need
```

Comment: The output is generated from the line:      System.out.println(heap.toString());  
in the first block of code. I see that toString() returns a String representation as the iterator would. I changed it to print using poll() and the output looks correct - thanks a lot!

Comment: @user681219:  Welcome to StackOverflow... don't forget to accept the answer if it answers your question correctly...

Answer (score 2):

PriorityQueues work on a "just in time" basis. If you just display their contents, the contents are not going to be in sorted order; they're in a heap (which, since you mentioned, I think you'd know about.) Anyway, to get the contents in order, you have to pull the items off one at a time with i poll().

Comment: I did know they were in a heap, but had (wrongfully) assumed toString() would print the PriorityQueue in sorted order. Thank you for correcting me.